# TextField renders differently in different PDF readers

Tags: hyperref

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\fbox{\TextField[name=foo,value=test123,maxlen=10,borderwidth=0pt]{input:}}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

The text fields are rendered differently in OSX Preview and in Adobe Reader.

I understand that the blue background is part of Adobe's user interface, but why is the input text rendered so much lower than in OSX preview? This results in different printing results, which is not acceptable.

Edit: Since I encountered this problem as well, I want to make clear that this is in fact a TeX issue. The problem is solved adding the multiline parameter:

```
\fbox{\TextField[name=foo,value=test123,maxlen=10,borderwidth=0pt,multiline=true]{input:}}
```

Comment: Complain with the PDF viewer developers. More than providing correct PDF code, `hyperref` can't do.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about rendering of PDF in different viewers. (The PDFs happen to be produced in TeX but that is not relevant to the question as far as I can see.)